# drop entire panel id/firm if at least 1 missing value for variable

Tags: stata

I have panel data and want to delete an entire panel id/firm ID if it has at least 1 missing total assets (at) in one of the years. Could someone help me?

So to be clear the panel data contains the following variables:

1) `year`: year

2) `gvkey`: firm id

3) `TotalAssets`: amount of Total Assets

So if a firm (id) has in one of the years at least 1 missing value for `TotalAssets`, then it needs to be completely removed out of the sample.

Comment: Someone not me downvoted this, and it is a fair guess that lack of code and lack of data example imply lack of effort to someone. That's just extra-sensory perception on my part.

Comment: Hi @NickCox,  I had ''drop if missing(TotalAssets)'', but it removes only the particular rows. The problem is that I want to delete the whole firm from the sample (which is represented by the firm id, GVKEY) if in one of the firm-year observations has a missing value for Total Assets.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't seem possible to have more than one missing value in any year and firm with annual data, but most of the question seems to imply that the criterion is one or more missing values within each panel. If you `sort` on the outcome variable within panels, then missing values are sorted to the end. So the last value will be missing if any values are missing and a `drop` is conditional on that:

```
 bysort gvkey (totalassets) : drop if missing(totalassets[_N])
```

Comment: Thanks @nickcox, I did: ''drop if missing(TotalAssets)'', but it removed only the particular rows.

What is the difference between bysort and sort exactly?

Comment: nvm. I have it already. Sorted the data back with Sort gvkey year